# Calling C functions. Who is calling

Tags: python

When python calls out to a C function using

```
static PyObject* Myfunction (PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
```

is there any way to know who the caller was, ie the function and module? This would allow me to have a single method that can dispatch a large number of methods. Ive thought of a hack such as passing the string names in the call followed by the arguments, eg

```
call ("math", "sin", 2.5)
```

But this is not ideal.

Comment: Such hidden dependencies are almost always a bad idea. My advice is to avoid doing it and instead being explicit about the requirements and dependencies of the method.

Comment: @rhody: has this got to do with logging or what?

Comment: It's to do with loading a dll and automatically exposing the methods at the python level. The dll has additional methods to obtain info on # of arguments etc for each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly get module + function, but you can get filename and function name for any Python (interpreted) stack frame.

The function returning a tuple with caller's filename and function name
Using C API:

```
#include <frameobject.h>

static PyObject* get_caller_info(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyCodeObject* code = PyEval_GetFrame()->f_code;
    return Py_BuildValue("(OO)", code->co_filename, code->co_name)
}
```

Note that frame object structure is not part of public API, use at your own risk.

The same thing done from Python using traceback module:

```
import traceback

def get_caller_info():
    filename, _, function_name, _ = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)[1]
    return filename, function_name
```

This information may not always be reliable. For example, all lambda functions get named `<lambda>`.

To get module module instance from a filename, you could create a cache like this:

```
_filename_to_module = {os.path.realpath(module.__file__): module
                       for module in sys.modules.itervalues()
                       if hasattr(module, '__file__')}
module = _filename_to_module.get(filename)
if module is None:
    # refresh the cache and retry
```

Comment: The python will be embedded in another app so I can guarantee a stack will be present. I think your suggestion could be the answer. I'll wait a little more before confirming.